# normalize space in xquery unexpected behavior

Tags: xquery

```
let $e as xs:string *:= ()
let $s as xs:string := ''
return (exists(normalize-space($s)), exists($s), exists(normalize-space($e)), exists($e))
```

returned true, true and  true, false.

I expect true, true, and false, false

I did not expect normalize-space of an empty sequence now exists seemed unexpected.

Comment: Where did your expectation come from? Were you just guessing what the spec might be, or were you using some resource that gave you misleading information? It would be nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-normalize-space says:

> If the value of $arg is the empty sequence, the function returns the
>   zero-length string.

So `normalize-space($e)` evaluates to the empty string `''` and `exists` of a non-empty sequence like the one with a single string (even if an empty string) returns true.

Comment: Note the background to this is that XQuery is trying to be compatible with XPath 1.0. XPath 1.0 does not have a result type of "xs:string?", so functions that return strings typically use the empty string as their "default/null" return value in such situations, and XQuery followed this lead.